# Cannot remove extra whitespace in a string retrieved from internet in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, file-get-contents, str-replace

I am trying to remove extra whitespace of a string I get from internet using file_get_contents(). I tried str_replace() andpreg_replace(), and also search but none of them worked.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $html_content = file_get_contents("http://mindcity.sina.com.hk/MC-lunar/daily/2014/12/20141209_b5.html");

$html_content =  mb_convert_encoding($html_content, 'UTF-8', 'BIG-5');
$html_content = strip_tags($html_content); 

$start_pos = strrpos($html_content, "宜 :");
$end_pos = strrpos($html_content, "凶神宜忌 :") - strlen($html_content);
$good_to_do = substr($html_content, $start_pos, $end_pos);
echo $good_to_do .'<br>';
//remove whitespace of $good_to_do
$good_to_do = str_replace(' : ','*',$good_to_do);
$good_to_do = preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u', '', $good_to_do);
$good_to_do = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", "\0", "\s", "\x0B", "\x20", "\xA0"), '*', $good_to_do);
var_dump( $good_to_do ); ?>
```

Comment: `$good_to_do - str_replace` that minus `-` should be an equal sign `=`

Comment: oh, a typo. But making it a equal sign still doesn't remove all the spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that the white space was `&nbsp;` when view source.
So the code just simply becomes `str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $html_content);`

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$good_to_do = preg_replace('/\s+/', '*', $good_to_do);
```

I put '*' because that is what you want to replace it with? You can put anything you like there.

Comment: It didn't remove all the space character in this case

Comment: Try this `foreach(preg_split('//',$var) as $char){
    var_dump(ord($char));
}` where $var is $good_to_do after ONLY applying the above regex and then post the output.

Comment: I notice there are chinese charcters. The spaces are probably not spaces but chracters that can not be rendered. The \s matches quite a few whitespace characters.

Comment: Try doing the mb_convert_encoding and strip tags, AFTER the space removal.

Comment: I applied the regex before doing `mb_convert_encoding()` but still multiple space left between the string

Comment: Did you do my foreach code above? This will give the character code of each character which will allow us to identify the spaces.

Comment: it give me outpuut like this: int(0) int(229) int(174) int(156) int(58) int(231) int(144) int(134) int(233) int(171) int(174) int(38) int(110) int(98) int(115) int(112)......

So how can I identify the space?

Comment: As I suspected. None of those are spaces. The pre_replace does work. There are some characters that the browser can not render.